# How do I run the cloudhopper demo as a Java application?

Tags: java, smpp

**How to use Twitter cloudhopper?**

I took the source code and tried to run the demo code as a Java application but I don't know to test it.

**Are there any tutorials for cloudhopper?**

Answer (score 4):

This library's implementation takes advantage of non-blocking (NIO) sockets to support thousands of binds using minimal resources. It can be used to implement either the server, client, or both sides of the SMPP protocol. It is used internally at Twitter for both. Both synchronous or asynchronous request modes can be supported on an SMPP session. Clients and servers can use TLS/SSL to provide communication transport security.

**You can find the best tutorial at Project Home site.. [Demo](https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp/tree/master/src/test/java/com/cloudhopper/smpp/demo) is available**

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer. Once you have a clone of the code you will find a makefile inside the root folder. Inside that makefile you have the maven commands that you should use to test either a test server or a test client.
to run Client:
`mvn -e test-compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.mainClass="com.cloudhopper.smpp.demo.ClientMain"`

To run server: `mvn -e test-compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="test" -Dexec.mainClass="com.cloudhopper.smpp.demo.ServerMain"`